# Why is my Python CSV code reading in each row as a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I'm working on a spin-off project from a Code Academy lesson and running into an error when trying to append a specific column from each row of a CSV to a list.

*The code from the lesson*:

```
import csv

with open('cool_csv.csv') as cool_csv_file:
  cool_csv_dict = csv.DictReader(cool_csv_file)
  for row in cool_csv_dict:
    print(row['Cool Fact'])
```

I need to read in each row from my CSV, and append the value of the "subject" column to the entries list.

```
import csv

entries = []

with open("list.csv") as list_csv:
  list_reader = csv.DictReader(list_csv)
  for row in list_csv:
    entries.append(row["subject"])
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> entries.append(row[“subject”]) TypeError: string indices must be integers

I get that the error is saying that the value passed by row was a string, so I can’t access it with the header name, but what I don’t get is why. My file is a valid CSV as far as I can see, and my code is no different to that in the lesson other than appending instead of printing (I tested print, same error.)

My CSV:

```
subject,subject_type
first,test
second,test
```

What have I done wrong that’s making my code read in a string instead of the csv row?

Comment: try with `list_reader`, not with `list_csv`

Comment: I’m voting to close this as off-topic/typo/can’t be reproduced. It’s essentially a typo, a trivial mixup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop the reader

```
  for row in list_csv:
      entries.append(row["subject"])
```

You are looping the list_csv by mistake.

Comment: Doh, so obvious now  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

as @AlirezaTajadod was saying, you are iterating over a bad object, you have to iterate over `list_reader`

```
with open("list.csv") as list_csv:
  list_reader = csv.DictReader(list_csv)
  for row in list_reader:
    entries.append(row["subject"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `list_reader` instead of `list_csv`. See the following example file, **marks.csv**.

```
id,subject,marks
1,English,20
2,French,21
3,Spanish,21
```

So we have,

```
import csv
list_reader = csv.DictReader(open("marks.csv"))
```

You may iterate over the rows of the CSV file by iterating over `list_reader`. So if we do a for loop like below

```
for row in list_reader:
    print row
```

It will print row like this,

```
{'id': '1', 'subject': 'English','marks': '20' }
{'id': '2', 'subject': 'French', 'marks': '21' }
{'id': '3', 'subject': 'Spanish','marks': '22' }
```

Now to get the subject value simply do print `row['subject']`